# How to print out the 16bit data before saving an image with plt.imshow(data) in Python?

Tags: python

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *
from numpy import NaN
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def julia(C):
    X = arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.005)
    Y = arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.005)
    M = zeros((len(Y), len(X)))
    plt.axis('off')

    for x_iter, x in enumerate(X):
        for y_iter, y in enumerate(Y):
            z = x + 1j * y
            pixel = NaN
            for n in range(1, 4096):
                z = z**2 + C
                if abs(z) > 2:
                    pixel = n
                    break

            M[y_iter, x_iter] = pixel

    # (Please help! here I want to print the calculated matrix elements out to check the actual data  values, but how to write out this piece of code?!)

    plt.imshow(M, cmap = cm.cubehelix, extent = (X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()))
    plt.savefig('julia.tiff')
```

I want to print the calculated matrix elements out to check the actual data values, but how to write out this piece of code?! Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just print `M` by `print("Calculated Matrix : ",M)`

Comment: Thanks. I had printed M before, but I could get only all  [[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]] I  couldn't obtain any reasonable matrix elements by print(M). The calculated matrix should be in the range [0, 65536], but not just all 1! Please, do you have any other suggestions? Any comment will be thankful.